# How to install apk directly on OTG USB pen drive?

Tags: android, android-install-apk, usb-otg

I have set in my manifest file `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` but not installed in external storage as USB.

I am able to install on external storage as SDCARD.

Also, I have tried adb commands such as :

```
   adb devices
   adb shell pm set-install-location 2
   adb shell pm get-install-location
```

But only able to transfer on SDCARD.

Please provide suggestion to install app directly on OTG Pen Drive.

Thank You...!!!

Comment: I guess that is not possibe at all.

Comment: Might be you are right @rekire but its consider external as sdcard so might be there is way to store in external as OTG usb pendrive.

Comment: Please keep in mind when the `installLocation` attribute was added vs. when the OTG support was added.

Comment: Can you more elaborate ?

Comment: There no feature like installLocation as USB. And it shouldn't be there as it breaks security of android system.